# Crawling local filesystem - how to test that

Tags: java, testing

I'm planning to build an application which would crawl a part of a local filesystem (a subtree) in a depth-first-search manner and process all files it finds, except for some configurable exceptions.

---

To give an example, let's say I have a directory structure like this:

```
> documents
  - generic-doc.txt
  > mails
    - mail-01.txt
    - mail-02.txt
    - mail-03.txt
    > unread
      - mail-04.txt
  > invoices
    > paid
      - invoice-01.pdf
      - invoice-02.pdf
    > unpaid
      - invoice-03.pdf
```

I also have an exclusion rule like this:

```
exclude = "documents/mails/unread | documents/invoices"
```

Given these data on input, my application would process the following documents:

- generic-doc.txt
- mail-01.txt
- mail-02.txt
- mail-03.txt

(e.g. it would process all files, except for those located in the documents/mails/unread and documents/invoices folders)

In future, I might need to implement various forms of exlusion rules.

---

**What is the best way to test the implementation of the crawling module (e.g. that when given an exclusion rule, the module would return the correct set of documents)? Can it be done without using a real filesystem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the exclusion ruling to a separate module/class/object and test that in isolation. Then make sure, that your crawler asks the ExclusionRule before processing a file.

A sketch

```
public interface FileExcluder {
   boolean isExcluded(File aFile);
}
```

Note that there is already the [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) that provides a similar service, maybe you can reuse that abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7 you can create a dummy Filesystem. (Assuming you are using that)

You can create an interface which can be mocked out for all file handling operations but it's likely to be much simpler to create test files and test those (and delete them when finished)

Comment: can you post a link to an implementation of a "dummy" file system in the context of Java 7?

Comment: @DavidSoroko I started, but some many methods to implement. ;)

Comment: and then, there is this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: Unfortunately our applications have to be Java 1.5 compatible. But thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @DušanRychnovský In that case you need to create an interface for all disk access which you can mock, or create the files in a temporary directory. These are likely to be better options anyway.